# Prolog doesn't return a value

Tags: prolog

I have the following code:

```
pair_list([X,Y],[[X,Y]]).
pair_list([E,Z|X],[K|Y]):- [E,Z]==K, pair_list(X,Y).
```

When I run it, it gives correct output for

```
?- pair_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]).
true ;
```

but when I run

```
?- pair_list([1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6], X).
```

I just get `false.`

My question is why don't I get `X=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`

Comment: Change `==` (comparison) to `=` (or move `[E,Z]` into the head).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there: all you need to do is moving `[E,Z]` into the head, eliminating `K`:

```
pair_list([X,Y],[[X,Y]]).
pair_list([E,Z|X],[[E,Z]|Y]) :- pair_list(X,Y).
```

[Demo 1.](https://ideone.com/UsfOmV)

Note that the base clause can be replaced with one based on empty lists:

```
pair_list([], []).
pair_list([E,Z|X],[[E,Z]|Y]) :- pair_list(X,Y).
```

[Demo 2.](https://ideone.com/gw2tO8)

Also note that your program is not going to work with a list that has an odd number of items. In order to fix this, add a separate base clause that handles a list with a single item either by dropping the item, making a pair with some fixed atom, or doing something else that you find useful in this case.

Comment: It makes more sense to fail if the list has an odd number of items.

Comment: @TomasBy It depends on OP's requirements, there may be situations when the list should be padded with some values.

Comment: If we assume the OP meant it the way he wrote it, then that would seem to suggest the requirement is to fail when length is odd number.